# Haskell - module inside module

Tags: haskell, module, yesod

I have a module like this:

```
module Model where

import FlowType
  .
  . 
  .
```

I am using `FlowType` in `Model`'s body, but I want also to export along with Model's functions FlowType's too. I found a module with the following syntax:

```
module Import
  ( module Import
  ) where

import Foundation as Import
  .
  . 
  .
```

What is this `module Import ( module Import) where`???
How can I do the same in my `Model` module (and also exporting its own functions)?

Comment: The `..` in `module X (..) where` is the exports list. If you don't specify it, the default is to export the entire module. You can explicitly re-export entire modules from your module - the fact that you can also rename a module in an import is unrelated. `module Import ( module Import, module Foundation ) where import Foundation` accomplishes the same thing. However, a common idiom is to import many modules with a single qualifier, then reexport them all at once - as you see in the latter example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose the module `Foundation` exports the names `foo` and `bar`.

First, `import Foundation as Import` makes those names available as `Import.foo` and `Import.bar` inside the module currently being defined.

The `module` statement then exports those names as well. Instead of having to write

```
module Import (foo, bar) where
```

you can export everything accessible via the name `Import` with the syntax in the question. The example is a little confusing since it uses `Import` both as the internal name for `Foundation` and as the name of the current module. It would be more obvious written as

```
module Import (module Foundation) where

import Foundation
  .
  .
  .
```

In your case, you would write

```
module Model (module FlowType) where
import FlowType
```

to export everything imported from `FlowType` from your module.

Comment: How about the `module Model (import FlowType) where` plus the functions from the module itself?

Comment: You can use the `module Model` in the export list itself. `module Model (module FlowType, module Model) where`.

Comment: If I would to filter some functions from both Model and FlowType, how would it be like?

Comment: Please stop asking further questions in the comment section.